# Why is there an t string syntax error?

Tags: php

I dont understand why this is giving me an t string syntax error. It looks to me correct! Can somebody please help me out? I am few weeks into my php learning attempt and just trying to make sense of this jumble. I know this is something incredibly stupid but I cannot figure it out!

```
<?php 
// set up some variables 
// the toys 
$item1 = "X−ray specs"; 
$item2 = "Watch with built−in poison gas canister";
$item3 = "Exploding chewing gum"; 
// the price 
$item1_cost = 100; $item2_cost = 250; $item3_cost = 32; 
// the amount
$item1_qty = 1; $item2_qty = 2; $item3_qty = 15; 
// calculate cost for each item 
$item1_total = $item1_cost * $item1_qty;
$item2_total = $item2_cost * $item2_qty; 
$item3_total = $item3_cost * $item3_qty; 

// calculate grand total
$grand_total = $item1_total + $item2_total + $item3_total; 
//special secret agent discount − 10% 
$discount = 10; 
// which reduces total bill amount 
$amount = ($grand_total * 10)/100;
// the bottom line 

$net_total = $grand_total − $amount; 

?>
```

Comment: Having the error message would help. See if you can add it before this gets closed as too localized.

Comment: You set `$discount = 10` but you didn't use it. Not a big deal since this is beginner but just letting you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you managed to use "–", an n-dash, instead of "-", a minus sign. Did you copy/paste it from a web article? That might have done it. You might also encounter this sort of error if you have `“` or `”` instead of `"`, which happens fairly frequently with copying code from web pages.

Change this

```
$net_total = $grand_total − $amount;
```

to this

```
$net_total = $grand_total - $amount;
```

or just retype the line.

Comment: LOL!!! I ran it on my server and I was like.. what the heck, that line looks fine.. good snag!

Comment: Oh Gosh! Thanks for the reply! I copied this from an tutorial..